# sony camera api controlling multiple cameras

Tags: sony-camera-api

Can I use the Sony Camera API to set off 5 or 6 (or more) Action Cams at the same time or in a sequence? Then grab the image from each one?

I know the action cam remote can control five devices - but that may be using non public APIs.

I've scanned the doc's and not sure if I can connect to many cameras at once / sync them all taking photos at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only connect to one Action Cam at a time since it requires a direct WiFi connection between the phone/tablet and the Action Cam and the phone cannot support more than one WiFi connection at once.

Comment: I posted a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28151838/678801), about accessing the API while having the camera connected to my smartphones tethered WiFi. I'd much appreciate if you could address it.

Answer (score 1):

Revival of an old thread. I've been hunting, but,  has anyone come across anything that makes it possible to control 2 or more dsc-qx10/qx100 cameras (or the like) with a single smartphone? The playmemories app is capable (so I've read) only not with these devices. Only the NEX I believe.

Answer (score 0):

A direct wi-if connection shouldn't prevent more than one camera from connecting at once. Wifi is a wireless Ethernet. Any devices connected to the same ssid should be able to communicate with each other which would likely be how the rm-lvr1 would handle Multicam. I' researching the same thing myself for a summer bike tour and concert series I'd like to livestream.

Currently it looks like the hardware is more than capable but the software is not yet available. I'll have to look through the API to see if there's any hope.

Comment: That's the problem, the *camera* is the A/P, so each one is a different SSID. Worse, the IP address of the camera seems to be 192.168.2.1 every time, so you have a routing problem. Ther'es another thread where someone describes successfully using Linux with multiple wireless adapters, and "namespaces" to address this successfully, but the configuration of the camera as A/P rather than a client (or at least *only* as A/P, with no option for a simple client) seems to be a major shoot-in-the-foot choice here.